# Change ansible role_path with vagrant provision

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I have a bunch of ansible galaxy roles and a bunch of custom roles.

The problem is that I can't load custom roles AND galaxy roles at the same time using a Vagrantfile `:ansible` provisionner.

Without vagrant, this command works well as I added the `ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH` environment variable:

```
 ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH=./custom_roles ansible-playbook project.yml --inventory dev.ini -vvvv --ask-sudo-pass
```

My Vagrant configuration is the following:

```
config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
   ansible.raw_arguments = ['--timeout=300']
   ansible.playbook = "project.yml"
   ansible.verbose = "vvv"
   ansible.groups = {
     "env-dev:children" => ["app-web", "app-db"],
     "app-web" => ["my-app"],
     "app-db" => ["my-app"],
   }
 end
```

I can see that ansible auto-load roles inside `./roles` but I can't add my custom roles to this directory due to version control (`./roles` is in my `.gitignore`)

Here is the directory structure to have a better view of what's going on:

```
 - roles/
     - postgresql/...
     - php/...
 - custom_roles/
     - my-role-1/...
     - my-role-1/...
 - .gitignore         <- ignore ./roles
 - project.yml
 - roles.yml
 - dev.ini
 - Vagrantfile
```

Comment: Have you tried to place all roles in the single `ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH` directory?

Comment: Yes that works but it's not practical. I need to `.gitignore` the ansible galaxy roles and I need to commit my custom roles. I shouldn't be listing every role independently in the ignore file

Comment: I understand, unfortunately that is how I am dealing with it, I would care to see some other options.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I had the same problem, and found a workaround by setting the `ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH` environment variable.

In the `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  vagrant_root = File.dirname(__FILE__)
  ENV['ANSIBLE_ROLES_PATH'] = "#{vagrant_root}/infrastructure/provisioning/ansible/roles:#{vagrant_root}/infrastructure/provisioning/ansible/galaxy-roles"

  # ansible provisioning
  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = 'infrastructure/provisioning/ansible/playbook.yml'
    ansible.galaxy_role_file = 'infrastructure/provisioning/ansible/dependencies.yml'
    ansible.galaxy_roles_path = 'infrastructure/provisioning/ansible/galaxy-roles'
  end
end
```

Comment: if you use a modified (or original) role than you only need `ansible.galaxy_roles_path` ! cheers